# How to change ComboBox Arrow image in Wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

Actually i search many blogs and tutorials related to ComboBox arrow in Wpf.

I want to design combo box like bellow image:

[image]

Please provide codes for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to either extract the template of the CombBox using Blend or VS, or retrieve it from the MSDN, and modify it according to your style.

Answer (score 9):

You need to edit Combobox [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<Window.Resources>
        <!--Toggle Button Template-->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Grid x:Name="gd">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
                <Border x:Name="Boredr1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="1" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                <Path x:Name="Arrow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" TextElement.Foreground="Orange"></ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Boredr1" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 5 5 L 10 0"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="gd" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!--TextBox Template-->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!--combobox-->
        <Style x:Key="combobox_style" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate  TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Foreground="Black" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press">
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBox OverridesDefaultStyle="True" SelectionBrush="Gray" CaretBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,30,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap"   x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" FontFamily="Segoe UI Dark"   Foreground="Black" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Focusable="True"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="15"   Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup Name="Popup"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placement="Bottom"  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid Name="DropDown"   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">                                       
                                    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="DropDownBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Transparent" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent">
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

 <ComboBox Height="30" Style="{StaticResource combobox_style}" Width="200"></ComboBox>
```

[image]